# Should I store user_id in all tables to ease Row Level Policy checks

Tags: row-level-security

In a Postgres database serving classical multiuser web application, I’ve got multiple tables, including the user table.

user_id integer is what row level security policy is based on in the application.

Is it a good idea to denormalize user_id and put it to all tables, add foreign keys, and let policies use the column?

Is it practical in terms of getting policy checks work faster at the cost of increased memory consumed by indexes and te data itself?

I’m expecting tens of millions rows in every table (well, except the users table). I’m concerned about policy checks execution speed.

Kind of data stored, if that helps:

- 10k-500k records per user in the tables.
- Data both added (90%) and deleted (10%).
- Data added regularly on a daily basis.
- Plenty of complex aggregated, windowed and hierarchical queries.
- Data represents graphs, networks, and plenty of metadata attached to entities.
- approximately 30 tables

Comment: your other option is to use `update from`, `delete using` to make your policy checks

Comment: if you want speed go with one schema per user.

Comment: I need to protect data at the database level, not application level, so `update from` and `delete using` is not a viable option for me, right?

Comment: Is it best to ask this question here or at StackOverflow?

Comment: `update somedata set colname='newvalue' from docs where somedata.doc_id=docs.id and docs.userid='555' and somedata.id='6666'; `

Comment: Right, this is at the application level.